# $\lim_{x\to 1}\ln(1-x)\cot\frac{\pi x}2$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\ln(1-x)\cot\frac{\pi x}2$$
After applying L'Hospital twice, I get 
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{-2\sin\pi x}\pi = 0$$

Is this correct? And if I do by LHL and RHL method, ln(1-x) would not be defined for RHL since the log of negative is not defined. Also the concern that tan($\pi$/2) approaches +$\infty$ from LHL and -$\infty$ from RHL.

Comment: $\text{cotan}(\pi x/2)$ is $\sim x-1$ near 1 which goes much stronger to zero then the log diverges so i think ur result is correct

Comment: Thanks mate. :) Any counter arguments would be much appreciated from people on stackexchange..

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{\log(1-x)\cos\frac{\pi x}2}{\sin\frac{\pi x}2}=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac1{\sin\frac{\pi x}2}\cdot\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{\log(1-x)}{\frac{1}{\cos\frac{\pi x}2}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=1\cdot\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac2\pi\frac{-\frac1{1-x}}{-\frac{\sin\frac{\pi x}2}{\cos^2\frac{\pi x}2}}=\frac2\pi\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac1{\sin\frac{x\pi}2}\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{\cos^2\frac{\pi x}2}{1-x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=1\cdot\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{-2\cos\frac{\pi x}2\sin\frac{\pi x}2}{-1}=0$$

So yes: your result is correct **but only as one-sided limit**, as the function's isn't defined on any right neighborhood of $\;1\;$ (the splitting of limits is justified since each limit by itself exists finitely)

Comment: But for x approaching from 1-  i.e. LHL, the log would not be defined. Can we still claim that since RHL is 0 and LHL is not defined, the result would be 0?

Comment: @T.Pal No, we can't. The limit  cannot exist since the function isn't even defined on any right neighbourhood of $\;1\;$, so all we can say is the *left* limit at $\;1\;$ exists and vanishes. BTW, I confused between $\;+\;$ and $\;-\;$ in the limits. It is corrected now

Comment: Yes that's my concern. So essentially, the limit does not exist as it only exists for one side and not the other and hence no question of equality between LHL and RHL. Is that it?

Comment: @T.Pal Indeed so.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not defined for $x>1$; in this case writing $\lim_{x\to1}$ or $\lim_{x\to1^-}$ is just a question of conventions.

A possible simplification is to set $1-x=\frac{2t}{\pi}$, so we have
$$
\cot\frac{\pi x}{2}=
\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)=
\tan t
$$
and the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\ln\frac{2t}{\pi}\tan t=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\ln\frac{2}{\pi}\tan t+\ln t\tan t\right)=0
$$
because the first summand has limit $0$ and the second can be written
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}(t\ln t)\frac{\tan t}{t}=0\cdot 1=0
$$

Comment: Interesting. This proves that the limit indeed is zero. Also I understand that  it was a mere formality to prove the RHL since the function is not even defined for x>1 and I could have concluded that the limit is ZERO without carrying out the RHL proof explicitly. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: @T.Pal The limit from the right is meaningless.

Comment: But then your proof works for Right limit and shows it is zero, albeit using a substitution to simplify.

Comment: @T.Pal If $x<1$, then under the substitution we have $t>0$, so $\lim_{x\to1^-}$ becomes $\lim_{t\to0^+}$

Comment: Missed that. So only one sided limit exists as the other side is meaningless in R. Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

Lim log(1-x) cot(pi x/2)

x->1

Let x-1=t

Lim log t cot((pi/2)(t+1))

t->0

Lim log t cot((pi/2) +(pi t/2))

t->0

Lim log t tan(pi t/2)

t->0

Lim log t /cot(pi t/2)

t->0

On putting limit, we get infinity/infinity form. Therefore we can apply L 'Hospital rule

Lim -1/[(pi/2)cosec²(pi t/2)]

t->0

Lim sin²(pi t/2)/(pi t/2)

t->0

Multiplying and  dividing by pi t/2

Lim (sin²(pi t/2) / (pi t/2)² )× pi t/2

t->0

Using lim x->0 sin²x/x² =1

Lim pi t/2

t->0

=0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. When you post a question with a lot of math typing, maybe try using https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.